# браузер не видит мой сервер

Tags: nginx

Всем привет. Начал изучать работу с nginx + go server
Есть вот такой сервер go

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func main() {
    log.Println(make_server().ListenAndServe())
}

func make_server() *http.Server {
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    return &http.Server{
        Handler: router,
        Addr:    ":8282",
    }
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("Hello!"))
}
```

Находится он в папке `$HOME/work/src/server`
А вот конфиг nginx для проксирования запросов с nginx на go сервер.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name some_domain;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/derror.log;

location $HOME/work/src/server {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.109:8282/;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

И лежит он в `/etc/nginx/sites-available/some_domain`

Но когда я запускаю nginx и go сервер и пытаюсь зайти на `http://some_domain/` то получаю "Сервер не найден" в браузере.
При этом если заходить по `192.168.1.109:8282/`то go сервер работает
Что я делаю не так? Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Ты не сделал настройку разрешения доменного имени some_domain на машине, с которой заходишь в браузере по ссылке http://some_domain/. Используй в качестве IP DNS-сервера в настройках сетевого адаптера или в настройках клиента разрешения DNS-имён тот DNS-сервер, который разрешает доменное имя some_domain в правильный IP-адрес (IP-адрес настроенного тобой веб-сервера), или пропиши сопоставление доменного имени с этим IP в файле hosts.

Comment: Я добавил запись в hosts, но это не помогло